# Implementação de uma classe e a utilização de interface como referência de objetos

Tags: java, objetos, interface

Estou com dificuldade em entender uma questão que eu deveria implementar.

Considere a interface abaixo:

```
public interface Comparavel {
/**
  * Assinatura de método que toda classe que quer permitir a comparação entre seus objetos precisa 
  *implementar
  *
  * @param o - Objeto que será comparado.
  * @return 0 se os objetos forem iguais.
  *         > 0 se o objeto recebido é menor que o objeto que será comparado.
  *         < 0 se o objeto recebido é maior que o objeto que será comparado.
  */
  public abstract int comparar(Object o);
}
```

a) Faça as alterações necessárias para a classe Pessoa, de forma que ela implemente corretamente a interface Comparavel. O critério de comparação de duas pessoas deve
ser a sua idade.

b) Crie uma classe que permita realizar a comparação entre duas pessoa, utilizando a interface
implementada como referencia de objetos.

Assim está a classe Pessoa:

```
public class Pessoa implements Comparavel{

    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    @Override
    public int comparar(Object o) {
        if(o.getIdade() < this.getIdade()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(o.getIdade() > this.getIdade()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Entretanto, claramente a comparação entre as idades não funciona. Além disso, não entendi como deve ser feita a questão b. Agradeceria qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Provavelmente você estava esbarrando em `Cannot resolve method 'getIdade' in 'Object'`;

```
@Override
public int comparar(Object o) {
    Pessoa pessoa = (Pessoa) o;
    if (pessoa.getIdade() < this.getIdade()) {
        return 1;
    } else if (pessoa.getIdade() > this.getIdade()) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Efetuar o CAST para o tipo `Pessoa` é a solução já que toda classe herda por padrão de `Object`;

Segue a classe para comparar:

```
    public class ExecutorComparavel() {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

          // Retorna 0 porque é igual
          Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("A", 10);
          Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("A", 10);
          int resultado1 = p1.comparar(p2);

          // Retorna -1 porque a instancia recebida é maior que a comparavel
          Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("A", 10);
          Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("A", 11);
          int resultado2 = p1.comparar(p2);

          // Retorna 1 porque a instancia recebida é menor que a comparavel
          Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("A", 10);
          Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("A", 9);
          int resultado3 = p1.comparar(p2);
       }

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

- Mude o parâmetro da implementação do método comparar - da classe Pessoa - de Object para Pessoa.
  (ou faz o 'cast' do objeto parâmetro - para o tipo Pessoa - antes de chamar o método getIdade()).
- A questão b ele quer q vc crie uma classe que instancie dois objetos do tipo Pessoa, os popule e compare suas idades.

Mas para comparar suas idades, você deve usar a interface como tipo, algo assim

```
private int comparaPessoas(Comparavel pessoa1, Pessoa pessoa2) {
  return pessoa1.comparar(pessoa2);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui arrumar a letra A. Mas para a b, onde deveria ficar esse método criado comparaPessoas?